# mysql select all records with top 3 maximum values

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table and i want to get all records with top 3 maximum salaries.

```
userid    salary
1           10
2           20
3           20
4           30
5           10
6           50  
7           40
8           50
9           30
10          20
```

And result should be all records with 3 maximum values i.e.:

```
userid    salary
8           50
6           50
7           40
9           30
4           30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where salary in 
(
   select * from (select distinct salary from your_table order by salary desc limit 3) tmp
)
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14689/7)

Comment: Nor working, limit is not supported with IN clause in subquery

Comment: still didn't work, it gives 3 records only but i want all records with 3 maximum salaries like i mentioned above.

Comment: `distinct` was missing.

Comment: Yes it's working, Thanks. One more question in the same query.

select * from your_table
where sal in 
(
   select * from (select distinct salary as sal from your_table order by salary desc limit 3) tmp
)

Please note i have now used 'sal' as alias of 'salary' and want to use it with 'where'. But it's not working. Please help me out

Comment: You can use aliases from inner selects. but `select * from your_table where sal in ()` does not work since you do not mean `sal` from the inner select. You mean `salary` from the outer select.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this...

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM t 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(salary,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(salary ORDER BY salary DESC) FROM t))  <= 4
 ORDER 
    BY salary DESC
     , userid DESC;
```

... although I suspect that this is faster...

```
SELECT userid
     , salary
  FROM
     ( SELECT t.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = salary THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END rank
            , @prev := salary
         FROM t
            , (SELECT @i:=0, @prev:=null) vars
        ORDER 
           BY salary DESC
            , userid DESC
     ) x
 WHERE rank <= 3;
```